# How to make a 3 dot pop up menu in app-bar in flutter. Image link is below

Tags: flutter, popup, appbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiqH3.png)As per image I want popup in app-bar in flutter

[image: As per image I want popup in app-bar in flutter]

Comment: share code what you have done

Comment: you only want that button there?

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code and you will store the SVG image in image directory

```
actions[
    Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 5),
          child: GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.blue)),
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "images/ic_more.svg",
                  height: 30,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onTapDown: (details) {
                _showPopUpMenu(details.globalPosition);
              })
        )
]
```

popUpMenu:

```
_showPopUpMenu(Offset offset) async {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double left = offset.dx;
    double top = offset.dy;
    double right = screenSize.width - offset.dx;
    double bottom = screenSize.height - offset.dy;

    await showMenu<MenuItemType>(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom),
      items: MenuItemType.values
          .map((MenuItemType menuItemType) =>
              PopupMenuItem<MenuItemType>(
                value: menuItemType,
                child: Text(getMenuItemString(menuItemType)),
              ))
          .toList(),
    ).then((MenuItemType item) {
      if (item == MenuItemType.EDIT) {
       // here set your route 
      }

    });
  }
```

And your enum data for popup menu

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

enum MenuItemType {
  EDIT,
  DUPLICATE
}


getMenuItemString(MenuItemType menuItemType) {
  switch (menuItemType) {
    case MenuItemType.EDIT:
      return "Edit";
    case MenuItemType.DUPLICATE:
      return "Duplicate";
  }
}
```

Comment: you can share with me this method  _showPopUpMenu(details.globalPosition .

Comment: i will share with you but you need practice

Comment: ok, just share with me

Comment: Update my answer please check.

Comment: i have check but i want to change background color of popup as show in image. grey color is there. you can also check my updated image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiqH3.png

Comment: is this work for you please mark as answer

Comment: and updated my answer please check, just wrap with a container circle shape

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to below code

Using custom_pop_up_menu: ^1.2.2

https://pub.dev/packages/custom_pop_up_menu

[image]

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ChatModel> messages;
  List<ItemModel> menuItems;
  CustomPopupMenuController _controller = CustomPopupMenuController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    menuItems = [
      ItemModel('Chat', Icons.chat_bubble),
      ItemModel('Add', Icons.group_add),
      ItemModel('View', Icons.settings_overscan),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CustomPopupMenu'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          CustomPopupMenu(
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.more_horiz,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 24.0,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 30.0,
                vertical: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
            menuBuilder: () => ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: menuItems
                        .map(
                          (item) => GestureDetector(
                            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                            onTap: _controller.hideMenu,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 40,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                              child: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    item.icon,
                                    size: 15,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                                      child: Text(
                                        item.title,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            pressType: PressType.singleClick,
            verticalMargin: -10,
            controller: _controller,
            barrierColor: Colors.black54,
            horizontalMargin: 0.0,
            arrowColor: Colors.white,
            showArrow: true,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Pop up menu",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Solution Using PopupmenuButton

[image]

```
Widget popMenus({
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> options,
  BuildContext context,
}) {
  return PopupMenuButton(
    iconSize: 24.0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.more_horiz_rounded,
      color: Colors.black,
      size: 24.0,
    ),
    offset: Offset(0, 10),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext bc) {
      return options
          .map(
            (selectedOption) => PopupMenuItem(
              height: 12.0,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    selectedOption['menu'] ?? "",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(14.0),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                  (options.length == (options.indexOf(selectedOption) + 1))
                      ? SizedBox(
                          width: 0.0,
                          height: 0.0,
                        )
                      : Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 8.0,
                          ),
                          child: Divider(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(1.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                ],
              ),
              value: selectedOption,
            ),
          )
          .toList();
    },
    onSelected: (value) async {},
  );
}

class PopUpmenusScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PopUpmenusScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PopUpmenusScreenState createState() => _PopUpmenusScreenState();
}

class _PopUpmenusScreenState extends State<PopUpmenusScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Examples"),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 4.0,),
            child: popMenus(
              context: context,
              options: [
                {
                  "menu": "option 1" ?? '',
                  "menu_id": 1,
                },
                {
                  "menu": "option 2" ?? "",
                  "menu_id": 2,
                },
                {
                  "menu": "option 3" ?? "",
                  "menu_id": 3,
                },
                {
                  "menu": "option 4" ?? "",
                  "menu_id": 4,
                },
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Examples"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.more_horiz,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 20.0,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: i have check but i want to change background color of popup as show in image. grey color is there. you can also check my updated image i.stack.imgur.com/tiqH3.png

Comment: Please check edited code solution using custom pop up menu

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily using [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) which is customizable Flutter's core DropdownButton.

It has `customButton` parameter which will replace the normal Button with Image, Icon or any widget you want. You can customize everything and design what you need by using many options described with the package. Also, you can change the position of the dropdown menu by using the `offset` parameter.

Here's an example of using DropdownButton2 as a Popup Menu with Icon:

[image: DropdownButton2 with Icon]

```
class CustomButtonTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomButtonTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomButtonTest> createState() => _CustomButtonTestState();
}

class _CustomButtonTestState extends State<CustomButtonTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton2(
            customButton: const Icon(
              Icons.list,
              size: 46,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            customItemsIndexes: const [3],
            customItemsHeight: 8,
            items: [
              ...MenuItems.firstItems.map(
                        (item) =>
                        DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>(
                          value: item,
                          child: MenuItems.buildItem(item),
                        ),
              ),
              const DropdownMenuItem<Divider>(enabled: false, child: Divider()),
              ...MenuItems.secondItems.map(
                        (item) =>
                        DropdownMenuItem<MenuItem>(
                          value: item,
                          child: MenuItems.buildItem(item),
                        ),
              ),
            ],
            onChanged: (value) {
              MenuItems.onChanged(context, value as MenuItem);
            },
            itemHeight: 48,
            itemWidth: 160,
            itemPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
            dropdownPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
            dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
            dropdownElevation: 8,
            offset: const Offset(0, 8),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MenuItem {
  final String text;
  final IconData icon;

  const MenuItem({
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
  });
}

class MenuItems {
  static const List<MenuItem> firstItems = [home, share, settings];
  static const List<MenuItem> secondItems = [logout];

  static const home = MenuItem(text: 'Home', icon: Icons.home);
  static const share = MenuItem(text: 'Share', icon: Icons.share);
  static const settings = MenuItem(text: 'Settings', icon: Icons.settings);
  static const logout = MenuItem(text: 'Log Out', icon: Icons.logout);

  static Widget buildItem(MenuItem item) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
                item.icon,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 22
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
        Text(
          item.text,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  static onChanged(BuildContext context, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item) {
      case MenuItems.home:
      //Do something
        break;
      case MenuItems.settings:
      //Do something
        break;
      case MenuItems.share:
      //Do something
        break;
      case MenuItems.logout:
      //Do something
        break;
    }
  }
}
```